# page not found error on Django 3 by examples tutorial

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

I'm learning Django and I'm trying to get a blog application running but I keep getting the same error:
[page not found error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTRFG.png)

I even went to the files available in [github link](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Django-4-by-example/tree/main/Chapter01) which are the endgoal (while slightly different)
I imported the whole mysite folder, opened a virtual env, installed Django, pushed the migrations and ran the server but I still get the same error.

It seems the problem arises with both my code and with the reference code in the github files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't target the good url.

According to your project url showed in the error, you have `admin/` and `blog/`

Then try `http://localhost:8000/blog` instead of `http://localhost:8000/`

Answer (score 0):

For any one encountering the same problem:

As Rvector stated the http://localhost:8000/blog is what we're supposed to use in the tutorial but I was just reading without paying enough attention and got hung up on the page not found error.

As an alternative replacing the:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
]
```

In `urls.py` in the mysite folder with:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
]
```

Will make the blog page run as the home page and http://127.0.0.1:8000/ will work fine, seems obvious now but I guess reading more slowly can save you a lot of time.